# Linux Shell, The "return" doesn't work while read a file

Tags: linux, sh

I read a file in my bash file, like this:

```
function read_config(){
cat $config_path | while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
    return 1
done

echo "not return"
return 0
}
```

$config_path is a normal file(not empty).
but,this function return 0 and echo "not return"
Could someone explain to me why this happens?

AND THEN
I did anther test, this code worked fine, it return 1:

```
function read_config(){
while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
    return 1
done < $config_path

echo "not return"
return 0
}
```

Is there any difference between these two pieces of code?

Comment: The pipe symbol always creates a subprocess. In your first case all in the while-loop is in a subprocess. A return in a subprocess does not work. Additionally all variables you fill in the loop will be gone after the loop finished. The second example does not start a subprocess.

Comment: The POSIX standard does not mandate a new process, but `bash` creates one by default. `ksh` does not, and `bash` and `zsh` have options to allow the final command in a pipeline to execute in the same shell that started the pipeline.

Comment: I get it, Thanks a lot !